# Typo3 with MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3

Is it possible to use TYPO3 with the MVC pattern? If so, what would be the right steps to do? At first developing my MVC website with Visual Studio and then implementing it in TYPO3?

Comment: Well thanks for your reply. In fact, I will give typo3 a try and see what it does. Being a student, I started a new job today and they use typo3 there so it would be nice to master that one. You should be honest to yourself that 2.7 mio lines of code could indeed never be error free and for being an open source project and you can try it for free, typo3 is a badass. Try sth for free, live with errors. Want sth error free, pay money. That's life as seen so often and I can totally live with that ;-)

Comment: The question was if it is possible to use TYPO3 with MVC. So the discussion about TYPO3 being worst or best is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo3 already has an MVC pattern implemented, especially if you're using the v6 branch, have a look at extbase, which splits model, view and controller in a really good way.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at extbase. Any ideas in which order I should develop?

Comment: Usually, you start with the model, and then implement first versions of controllers and views. After that, you'd change the stuff until it works like you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start an Extbase/Fluid extension in TYPO3 is to use the extension named "Extension Builder". It has a UI for model scaffolding, you can add controllers and backend modules. More information can be found in its manual:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/2.5.2/

Also there is a free e-book "Developing TYPO3 Extension with Extbase and Fluid" to be found here:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/

Extbase and Fluid are quite straight-forward to learn and cover a lot of needs out of the box.